# Метод жизненного цикла активности после закрытия вызываемой активности. Android

Tags: android

Имеется следующий вопрос. У меня активность (назовем ее А) вызывает другую активность (назовем Б). Активность Б выполняет различные действия и в один момент вызывается метод finish(), т.е. активность Б закрывается и открывается опять активность А. В связи с этим появился вопрос: какой метод в этом случае вызывается у активности А? onCreate() опять или onRestart() и onStart()?

Comment: onPause()->onStop() и потом снова onStart()->onResume()

Comment: вообще можно было бы переопределить эти методы, в них вызывать запись в лог Log.d("dev ", "onStart()"), и прямо на реальном примере посмотреть, что вызывается, а что - нет)

Comment: @UjinUkr, посмотрел по дебаггеру - вы правы. Запишете как ответ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

onPause()->onStop() и потом снова onStart()->onResume(). [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Больше информации можете узнать [здесь](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle).